# SharePoint Display Templates doesn`t work with hyphen

Tags: 2013, 2016, enterprise-search, display-template, managed-property

As it seems hypens in Managed Properties are still an issue in SharePoint 2016 / 2013.
I had an issue with an existing business application and did some tests to find out more.

I created two managed properties "testdummy" and "test-dummy" with exactly the same settings and the same mappings to the crawled property "Title".

If I use "testdummy" and "test-dummy" in a query term (enterprise result page)

```
"testdummy":test
```

or

```
"test-dummy":test
```

I get exactly the same results. Trying the same from the SharePoint Search Query Tool, it also works.

Even using one of those as a refinement property, by editing a refinement panel it also works like a charm.

Until now those properties where created for the exclusive use by external Rest Search calls, and even there (get and post calls), it worked.

But not inside a display template.
In order to use the property inside a Display Template I took a copy of an existing display template and added the properties one after another to the ManagedPropertyMapping Setting

`<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'testdummy':'testdummy',`

After that I verified the modification by looking at the automatically created javascript equivalent.

```
ctx['DisplayTemplateData']['ManagedPropertyMapping']={'testdummy':['testdummy'],
```

Looked good and worked as expected.

Then I tried the same with the test-dummy property.

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'test-dummy':'test-dummy',
```

and verified in the js file

```
ctx['DisplayTemplateData']['ManagedPropertyMapping']={'test-dummy':['test-dummy'],
```

But if I now use that template (no calculation is done with the property, just added to the mapping section), the only response on the page is a correlation ID.

Searching in the ULS Log I can find this information:

> The field name 'test-dummy' is not valid. Field names can only contain
>   English letters, digits, the underline character '_', and the
>   punctuation mark '.'

Any idea how I could "escape" that issue in a display template? In any other Use case I have, it works like intended.

Answer (score 2):

Hyphens in managed property names are a bad idea. If you consider that KQL uses the hyphen to negate the terms that follow, for example:
`Matthew -LastName:McDermott`

Will return items with the keyword "Matthew" but not the LastName "McDermott".

In my experience with SharePoint on-prem and online, if you introduce a managed property with a hyphen the query parser will not understand your query.

Comment: I know about the issue within KQL, and like I have written in my Question with the addition of quotation marks -> "test-dummy" you can still use it in KQL. As it is an already existing business application which has been running quite some time and all Use Cases (Query, Refinement, Rest-call,…) work. My question was if there is a way to do the escaping in a display template. If not, I already know that the whole application has to be modified to use a non-hyphen property.

Comment: I tried about a dozen different replacement and none worked.